# How to Show Google Finance like data in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-finance

Is there a way to show index prices by specific date like in google finance on wordpress?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  |  Your question is to open-ended. Wordpress is a Content-Management-System with an API. Data can be stored and served to a frontend via rest api. Using wordpress you can also get data from an external source. What are you trying to achieve, what have you done so far to get to a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily install a plugin to show index prices by specific date alongside  historical prices and information for various different stock, index, currencies or commodities without the need to code.

You're not limited to just historical charts there are many options available, such as tickers and cool widgets with live updates! Have a search yourself here, https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/